# How to generate Deterministic finite automaton for given language

Tags: algorithms, automata, finite-automata

**Problem:** Write a program which generates Deterministic finite automaton which accepts given language. Language is defined with alphabet and start/end sub strings.

For example: Alphabet={a,b,c}; start sub string="ab"; end sub string="cb"

I need to construct DFA which will accept strings of kind: {abcb, abaacb, abcabcb...}.

**Question:** What algorithm should I use to write function which will construct DFAs for this set of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to build the regular expression recognizing your language $L$.
It should look like this where $p_1,...,p_k$ are the start sub strings and $s_1,...,s_l$ are the end sub strings and $\Sigma$ is your alphabet:
$(p_1 | ... | p_k) \Sigma^* (s_1 | ... | s_l)$

In your example, your regular expression is $ab \Sigma^* cb$.
Using the [Thompson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction#Relation_to_other_algorithms), you get a NFA that accepts $L$.
This can be transformed into a DFA with the [power set construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).
As a last step you could minimze the DFA if necessary.

I am not sure if there would be a benefit to use a specialized construction, especially since all the algorithms mentioned above have been implemented and optimized for quite some time.

By the way, a "start substring" is called a *prefix*, the "end sub string" *suffix* and a "substring" *infix* in automata theory.